Calculating $\mathbb{E}\left[\tau\,W_{\tau}\right]$ when $\tau$ is first hitting time of asymetric barrier
Suppose $W$ is a Brownian motion. Let $\tau$ be defined as
$$
\tau = \inf\left\{t\geq 0\left| W_t-W_0\geq a\textrm{ or } W_t-W_0\leq -b\right.\right\}
$$
i.e. $\tau$ is the first time that $W$ hits either $+a$ or $-b$ (since $W_0=0$). We then have
$$
W_{\tau}-W_0 = Z
$$
with $Z$ a random variable with mean zero and point mass in $a$ and $−b$. More precisely $\mathbb{P}\left[Z=a\right]=b/(a+b)$ (hence $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$). It is also well-known that $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=a\,b$.
I need to compute the expected value
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\tau\,\left(W_{\tau}-W_0\right)\right]\quad(1)
$$
My guess is that $W_{\tau}-W_0$ can be treated as independent from $\tau$, hence the expected value is zero, but I am not sure and I cannot figure out how to proceed.

I assume $W_0=0$, without loss of gnerality.
The process $M_t:=W_t^3-3tW_t$ is a martingale, bounded up to time $\tau$. And $\Bbb E[W^3_\tau] = a^3{b\over a+b}-b^3{a\over a+b}$.
In particular, if $\tau$ and $W_\tau$ are independent then you must have $a=b$.

Thanks, this helps a lot. I guess that if $a=b$ we have that $\tau$ and $W_{\tau}$ have zero covariance, but by construction of $\tau$ they are still dependent.

They are independent when $a=b$, as one can argue by symmetry. This remains true in higher dimensions (replace the interval $[-b,b]$ by a ball centered at $0$). A converse (exit time and place independent implies region is a essentially a ball centered at starting point) was shown by L. Pitt in 1989.
